# Prompt for Name without any Variables

Tags: python

How would go about writing this program without any variables? It's super simple exercise from the book "57 Programming Exercises" but other than using importing sys and using the command line argv I don't see how to go about it. I think the intent is for it not to use sys.argv. Thank you.

```
inp = raw_input("What is your name? ")
print "Hello,",inp,"nice to meet you!"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
 print "Hello, {} nice to meet you!".format(raw_input("What is your name? "))
```

[format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) is just a way of inserting arguments in a string, similar to

```
print "Hello, " + raw_input("what is your name? ") + " nice to meet you"
```

Comment: format is actually a really nice way to insert variables in string without handling typing manually, for example `"Answer is {}.".format(1)`

Comment: Thanks Laurens! That nice and succinct.